# border layout with 3 content panels in gxt

Tags: java, gxt

I have border layout with west,center,east content panels. west panel should consist of checkbox list view which contains list of calculators. when we select any calculator it should dynamically load the respective calculator in the center panel and it should also display help text in east panel. how can we do this?????(this is our requirement) i mean how to dynamically link the checked item to center content panel? for now i have created a simple tree in west panel but we need to insert checkbox list view.

apart from checkbox list view if you have any other better option please let me know.......

Comment: To clarify, you have a JList with JCheckBox renderers/editors in the west panel? Or simply a JPanel that has a a lot of JCheckboxes in it that you're keeping track of in another way (List?)

Answer (score 0):

In the center create a Card Panel which consists of stack of all the calculators. Depending on the selection in the check box list view , get the index and select the calculator from the card panel.

Regarding updation of help in east panel use another card panel for stack of all help texts.